# How can I delegate organizational unit creation for other accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

Teoreticaly I can attach policies to manage Organization in AWS to any IAM user, I can do same in SCP manager in Organization panel for accounts.

But view with possibility to add and manage organizations is available only on master account. Same is when I try to do it from cli.

Is there possibility to delegate this responsibility that for example UNIT manager can create sub units in their own console?

Comment: Account has another meaning in AWS. Do you mean role, user or something else?

Comment: @nickolay.laptev - edited - I hope is more clear now